# Parent class returning instance of child class results in error in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop, webpack

I have a **CalendarEvents** and a child, inherited class called **SelectedEvents**. A SelectedEvents instance is returned when CalendarEvents.selected property is being accessed.

I get this error:

`CalendarEvents.ts:126 Uncaught TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null`

That leads to the `get selected(): SelectedEvents` line.

The error I got once Googled quickly led me to the circular dependency problem. I have created an index.ts file exporting all classes and interfaces hoping it'd solve the problem:

```js
// ./index.ts

export * from '../config';
export * from './classes/Blocker';
export * from './classes/CalendarEvent';
export * from './classes/CalendarEvents';
// no SelectedEvents because I tried putting it in the same file
export * from './classes/Selection';
export * from './classes/Slidedown';
export * from './interfaces/IcalendarEventHTMLElement';
export * from './interfaces/Idetail';
export * from './interfaces/IuncompletedRequest';
export * from './repeatWebRequest';
export * from '../config';
```

**It didn't**. I then thought to put the CalendarEvents and SelectedEvents to the same file, to no avail.

Here's the code (please ask if I removed something important):

```js
// ./classes/CalendarEvents.ts

import { CalendarEvent } from '..';

interface IcalendarEvents {
    [index: string]: CalendarEvent;
}

export class CalendarEvents {
    // no constructor class
    public events: IcalendarEvents;

    get calendarEvents(): CalendarEvent[] {
        return Object.values(this.events);
    }

    // supposedly errors here:
    get selected(): SelectedEvents {
        return new SelectedEvents(
            this.calendarEvents.filter((event: CalendarEvent) => {
                return event.selected;
            })
        );
    }
}

export class SelectedEvents extends CalendarEvents {
    constructor(selectedEvents?: Set<CalendarEvent> | CalendarEvent[]) {
        super();
        for (const event of selectedEvents) {
            this.events[event.eid] = event;
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe this is a bad design in general. If so, how else would something like this be accomplished? BTW this is all compiled with Webpack.

Comment: try adding a constructor to `CalendarEvents`

Comment: I feel like a dumb-dumb. I was discouraged by the ts-lint `no-empty` rule, but an empty constructor fixed this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into this issue again, here's how I fixed it:

Check your index.ts for the order of your imports/exports.

**Before:**

```js
export * from './classes/CalendarEvents';
export * from './classes/Events';
export * from './classes/SelectedEvents';
```

**After:**

```js
export * from './classes/Events';
export * from './classes/CalendarEvents';
export * from './classes/SelectedEvents';
```

Where `Events` is an abstract superclass of both `CalendarEvents` and `SelectedEvents`.